# How to implement listview according to Material design Guideline in android?

Tags: android

I have a Listview in my app containing Items,what I want to make my listview according to material design guideline and I saw google material design site but I have little confusion in that and don;t understand How to implement in my listview.
Kindly help me:-

[image]

and here is my code:-

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listSetting"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:scrollbarSize="4dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"/>
```

here what is Title Height 72 sp and how to implement and red marked numeric is padding or margin.

Comment: You should probably look up how to design a ListviewItem.

Answer (score 1):

[The official Documentation](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs) clearly says that `72dp` is `height of list item`. `16dp` is the Left and right `padding from screen edge.` where `8dp` is the `top padding`.

Comment: which one confused you? the left sided 72? or right top most one?

Comment: Which is the height of one list item. You may have n number of items

Comment: min height or max height

Comment: According to the design guidelines that's the height google suggested. fixed!

Comment: this height is of item layout or item

Comment: min or max height what